# How to type annotate anything that converts to `dict`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, python-typing, typing

As per title, I would like to know what would be the recommended way of typing something that would gracefully convert to `dict()`, e.g.:

```
import typing as typ

def foo(bar: <some_typing>) -> dict:
    return dict(bar)
```

I could use something like `typ.Union[dict, typ.Iterable[tuple[typ.Hashable, Any]]]` in place of `<some_typing>`, but I feel this is quite verbose, not complete (e.g. does not cover named tuples, custom classes, etc.) and there could (should?) be a cleaner alternative.

I am on Python 3.9, but if an answer could cover also earlier versions that would be a bonus.

Comment: If this is that general. why not just use `Any`?  Typing is supposed to help you.  If you spend more time trying to fit the tools, then the tools aren't helping.

Comment: @TimRoberts Because there is a good bunch of object that would **not** convert to `dict` and I want to catch those too.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/main/stdlib/builtins.pyi#L1018) are all possible options that `dict` can accept. For static type checking (and here it seems to represent runtime completely and properly) nothing besides these types can be passed to `dict`. There is no way to spell it shorter than union of that overloads without `**kwargs`, plus that overloads are better then your simple solution (both generic parameters can be deduced from argument, if you follow this route). Typeshed is often a source of solutions for builtins-related typing questions.